# Pascal and NSDs?

Tags: pascal

I have to make an assignment (in Dutch) for Programming Logic. We have to use Structorizer and than convert/export it into Pascal code (yes, I know, prehistoric! But they say it's like learning "latin", if you learn it you have like a base.)

Now, I already had to figure out several bugs while converting my var's. But the main question I'd like to ask is this:

How come if I type in STOP (where in code it says : Read naam) the while loop actually continues and prints out the next line : write naam ' moet', lidgeld:0:2, ' euro lidgeld betalen.'

Instead of just jump out of the while loop because of the 'STOP' and print out the bottom lines?

In other code, it is fairly easy to check the {} and step by step monitoring it. But here with this code I'm totally lost. I used already an IF statement after read naam to make 'stop' work, but then it still prints out again write naam ' moet', lidgeld:0:2, ' euro lidgeld betalen.'

Pascal Code:

```
    { Generated by Structorizer 3.26-05 }
program Vereniging;

var
  { TODO: check and accomplish variable declarations }

  leeftijd: integer ; kinderen : integer ; leden : integer ; inkomen : real ; totaal : real ; lidgeld : real ; gemiddelde : real ; naam : string;


begin
  lidgeld := 0;
  leden := 0;
  totaal := 0;
  gemiddelde := 0;
  writeln('Geef naam en voornaam in: ');
  readln(naam);
  writeln;
  writeln('Geef de leeftijd in: ');
  readln(leeftijd);
  writeln;
  writeln('Geef het aantal kinderen ten laste in: ');
  readln(kinderen);
  writeln;
  writeln('Geef het jaarinkomen in: ');
  readln(inkomen);
  while (naam <> 'stop') or (naam <> 'STOP') do
  begin
    lidgeld := 10;
    if (leeftijd > 50) then
    begin
      lidgeld := lidgeld - 2;
      leden := leden + 1;
      totaal := totaal + lidgeld;
      gemiddelde := totaal / leden;
    end;
    if (kinderen > 0) and (kinderen < 6) then
    begin
      lidgeld := lidgeld - kinderen;
      leden := leden + 1;
      totaal := totaal + lidgeld;
      gemiddelde := totaal / leden;
    end
    else
    begin
      lidgeld := lidgeld - 5;
      leden := leden + 1;
      totaal := totaal + lidgeld;
      gemiddelde := totaal / leden;
    end;
    if (inkomen < 12500) then
    begin
      lidgeld := lidgeld - 2.5;
      leden := leden + 1;
      totaal := totaal + lidgeld;
      gemiddelde := totaal / leden;
    end;
    if (leeftijd > 50) and (kinderen >= 5) and (inkomen < 12500) then
    begin
      lidgeld := lidgeld - 8.5;
      leden := leden + 1;
      totaal := totaal + lidgeld;
      gemiddelde := totaal / leden;
    end;
    writeln;
    writeln(naam, ' moet ', lidgeld:0:2, ' euro lidgeld betalen.');
    writeln;
    writeln('Geef naam en voornaam in: ');
    readln(naam);
    writeln;
    writeln('Geef de leeftijd in: ');
    readln(leeftijd);
    writeln;
    writeln('Geef het aantal kinderen ten laste in: ');
    readln(kinderen);
    writeln;
    writeln('Geef het jaarinkomen in: ');
    readln(inkomen);
    writeln;
  end;
  writeln;
  writeln('Het totaal aantal leden : ', leden);
  writeln;
  writeln('Het totaal aantal lidgeld : ', totaal:0:2, ' euro.');
  writeln;
  writeln('Het gemiddelde : ', gemiddelde:0:2, ' euro.');
  writeln;
  writeln('Druk op <ENTER> om het programma af te sluiten');
  readln();
end.
```

[NSD picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnKAR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition on your `WHILE...DO` loop is wrong - regardless of what you type in, *at least one* of those two conditions will be true, and the loop will execute (because `A OR B` is `TRUE` if *either* `A` is `TRUE` *or* `B` is `TRUE`):

If you type in `stop`, then the condition `(naam <> 'STOP')` will be true, and the loop will execute.

If you type in `STOP`, then the condition `(naam <> 'stop')` will be true, and the loop will executed.

What you want to do is compare with `'STOP'` in a *case-insensitive* manner, so that regardless of what you type - `STOP`, `stop`, `Stop`, `StOp`, etc. - the test will be `TRUE`. Or, alternatively, if you type anything other than some variation on the word `stop`, the test will be `FALSE`.

Comment: thank's for the help but it's still not fixed. I think it has something to do with my .nsd structure.

Comment: I can't help you with that; my familiarity is with the raw Pascal. But if you can guarantee that you'll either type `STOP` or `stop`, just change the `OR` in the condition on your `WHILE...DO` loop to `AND`.

Comment: I did but nothing changed. Let me ask another question that might help me out since you are experienced with Pascal. Inside the loop there is a readln(naam); if I type in stop in my program. Normally the while loop checks that readln(naam); for 'stop' no?

Comment: The `WHILE...DO` loop only checks once per iteration of the loop, at the very beginning. So, if the `READLN(...)` has code after it, between it and the end of the loop's `BEGIN...END` block, that code will be executed, regardless of the value provided to `READLN(...)`. It is only when the next iteration of the loop begins that the condition will be checked again, and at that point, if the condition evaluates to `FALSE`, the loop will terminate.

Comment: I figured it out. You were right with the case-insensitive manner.The compiler of structorizer who compiles the Nassi-Shneiderman Diagrams to Pascal code made a few mistakes on that issue. I compared the values and now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> I know, prehistoric...

Even if prehistoric, many programming languages *still have to learn something from pascal*. And many programmers too.

If you really want that, after typing "STOP" in reply to the program's prompt "Geef naam en voornaam in: ", the program stops to ask questions, then you have to add the following line:

```
if (naam='stop') or (naam='STOP') then break;
```

**exactly** after this line from you program:

```
readln(naam);
```

Otherwise, as said in the previous answer, you must change the cycle prologue like this:

```
while (naam<>'stop') AND (naam<>'STOP') do begin...
```

but this will not prevent the program to continue to ask for "*Geef de leeftijd*", "*Geef het aantal kinderen*", "*Geef het jaarinkomen in*".

Is it clear? The main bug depicted in your question is your understanding of programming, not the pascal language.

Comment: It's not so much the Pascal code that is wrong. It's using the compiler of Structorizer that transforms the NSD to Pascal/Delphi Code. I followed your first line of code, it had something to do with the case-insensitive manner. The condition of your last line is TRUE although there must be reasons why people don't use it so much anymore. But I'm not an expert and I surely don't want to get into a religious war.

Comment: @Sebastiaan Well: the code in your question does exactly what you complain about. Correct the code, and the program will do what you want. About case sensitivity, "stop" "STOP" "StoP" are all different in -case sensitivity-, and all equal in non-case-sensitivity. My suggested test is case-sensitive. If you prefer, you can write `if lowercase(naam)='stop' then break;` (case insensitive), and it will also catch "StoP". For pascal being little used nowadays, that is why I wrote "many programmers have to learn [about it]". But I, like you, don't want to start a religious war.

Comment: @Sebastiaan I took a look at the picture you posted. The test `<>'stop' OR <>'STOP'` _is already present there_. it's an original sin... :-)

Comment: Let me put it this way : I like programming in any language. But I still have a lot to learn ;-)